# how to run sonar on a simple java Web project?

Tags: sonarqube

Please help me to run sonar on simple web project .

I have a simple web project , not integrated with Ant or maven or anything , i wish to run sonar on my project . Can i do this ? If so How ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Check the following links to use sonar for non-maven projects.
http://sohamniyogi.wordpress.com/2012/12/20/sonar-setup-for-non-maven-java-project/
http://sanjitmohanty.wordpress.com/2012/05/24/355/
```